# Why can't I create this Route53 CNAME Alias?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm using `fake-domain` in place of what we really have.

This is what I have in R53 right now.

```
www.fake-domain.com     CNAME     xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
fake-domain.com         MX        {typical MX records}
fake-domain.com         NS        {aws name servers }
```

When I try to add a CNAME ALIAS for `fake-domain.com` to `www.fake-domain.com` I get the following error:

```
InvalidChangeBatch 400: RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name fake-domain.com. is not permitted as it conflicts with other records with the same DNS name in zone fake-domain.com.
```

What record is it conflicting with? I don't have an `A` and the only root levels are `MX` and `NS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Route53 Alias is only allowed when you have to point to AWS resources e.g. you may create cname alias to point to ELB DNS.

Comment: You are right! For one the AWS error was unhelpful. And in addition to that, the CF distribution didn't show in the Route53 alias drop-down, which just added more confusion. Turns out if you use a `*` wildcard in CF (which CF supports), it will not show up in Route53.